# Flutter Riverpod: Need to get old state from StateNotifierProvider before updating its state

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I am using Flutter with Riverpod and have the following question.  I currently have this StateNotifierProvider and some widget is listening to it:

```
final editMyProfileViewModelProvider =
    StateNotifierProvider.autoDispose<EditMyProfileViewModel>(
  (ref) {
    final myProfile = ref.watch(myProfileProvider).data.value;
    //
    // can I know the old state over here?
    //
    return EditMyProfileViewModel(
      myProfile: myProfile,
      read: ref.read,
    );
  },
  name: 'editMyProfileViewModelProvider',
);
```

Suppose that the state of the notifier changed. The provider will run and a new EditMyProfileViewModel will be created.  I would like to know the old state of the Notifier at the comment in the code. Is this possible??

Thanks for advance for any help.

Comment: in your state notifer class, create your method and return the previous by just calling state

Comment: My StateNotifierProvider is the the code above which is "editMyProfileViewModelProvider".  If I try to get its state from inside it, I will end up with endless recursion.  So that would not work.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways I have attempted to go about this:

1. (The obvious, but unwieldy way) Cache the old state in a private variable. Whenever the state is updated, update that variable in tandem, thus saving the old state.

```
int? _savedValue;
final usesSavedValueProvider =
    StateNotifierProvider<UsesSavedValueNotifier, int>((ref) {
  ref.watch(someChangingProvider);
  return UsesSavedValueNotifier(_savedValue  ?? 0);
});

class UsesSavedValueNotifier extends StateNotifier<int> {
  UsesSavedValueNotifier(super.state);

  set newValue(int newValue) {
    state = newValue;
    _savedValue = newValue;
  }
}
```

2. Use an AsyncNotifierProvider instead.

```
final fooProvider = AsyncNotifierProvider<FooNotifier, int>(FooNotifier.new);

class FooNotifier extends AsyncNotifier<int> {
   @override
   FutureOr<int> build() {
      ref.watch(someChangingProvider)
      return state.hasValue ? state.value : 0;
   }
}
```

Since changing state in the AsyncNotifier just fires off the build method, we can use state to get the previous value. HOWEVER, this results in an annoying behavior where anytime we want to read the provider it is treated as a future, making the call look like this:

```
ref.read(fooProvider).value!
```

Personally, I just threw a getter on the notifier to circumvent this.